# OSX laravel5 composer install zlib_decode(): data error

Tags: composer-php

Another project can be composer install,but laravel5 composer Will not work

Failed to decode response: zlib_decode(): data error
Retrying with degraded mode, check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#degraded-mode for more info

Answer (score 1):

It's because of poor or interrupted internet connections,In order to solve the problem change your internet form WiFi to Ethernet also make sure you don't have proxy programs running in background which sometimes interupt, worth to mention: some users might need to enable HTTP checking in setting section of ESET antivirus. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you have dev-master in your dependencies that may cause the problem. Try to write exact version of the the package that cause problem.

For instance 
instead of
"dimsav/laravel-translatable": "dev-master",
write
"dimsav/laravel-translatable": "~5.1.1",

In order to find out which package is trouble run this command: composer diagnose. hope this helps.