# Error when run "composer update". Windows / Vagrant / Laravel Homestead

Tags: php, laravel-5, vagrant, composer-php, zlib

Installed stack: Windows 7 64x / Vagrant / Oracle VM Box / Laravel Homestead.

Mapping works, laravel's site's works. But when I run command: "composer update"  - I get error message:

```
Failed to decode response: zlib_decode(): data error
Retrying with degraded mode, check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#degraded-mode for more info
```

P.S. I have done:

- Disable windows defender
- Turn off firewall
- Run composer clear cache
- Run composer diagnose - everything is ok
- php.ini - zlib is turned on
- there are no antivirus soft on my system

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OSX laravel5 composer install zlib\_decode(): data error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32295092/osx-laravel5-composer-install-zlib-decode-data-error)

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue! What works for me so far is disabling XDebug on the CLI, which at least allows degraded mode to work.

To make it work, run this command when SSH'd into your Homestead box:

`$ sudo phpdismod -s cli xdebug`

Hope it helps!